# I'm trying to change the useState object via handle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Here is the state object

```
   const [newQuestion,setNewQuestion] = useState({
        question:'', answers: [{
            answerText:'here',
            isCorrect:'here'
        },{
            answerText:'here',
            isCorrect:'here'
        },{
            answerText:'here',
            isCorrect:'here'
        },
        ]
        }
    )
```

And I try to update them through the form

```
 <>
                <div className='question-section'>
                    <div className='question-count'>
                        <span >Question {currentQuestion}</span>/{questions.length}
                    </div>
                    <div className='question-text'>

                        <input style={{color: 'white'}}
                               value={newQuestion.question}
                               name="question"
                               onChange={handleChange} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='answer-section'>
                    {newQuestion.answers.map((answers) => (
                        <input style={{color: 'white'}}
                               name="answerText"
                               value={answers.answerText}
                               onChange={handleChange} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </>
```

It looks like this

[image: form]

The name of the question changes, but the answer options do not change, why??

**handleChange is here**

```
    const handleChange = (event) => {
    setNewQuestion({ ...newQuestion, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
}
```

Comment: What is the `handleChange` function?

Comment: @CertainPerformance changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state object contains 2 properties: a `question` string, and an `answers` array. Doing

```
setNewQuestion({ ...newQuestion, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
```

will not update the `answers` array, but add a new outer property.

Use the index of the answer being iterated over to identify which item to replace in the answers array.

```
                    {newQuestion.answers.map((answers, i) => (
                        <input style={{color: 'white'}}
                               name="answerText"
                               value={answers.answerText}
                               onChange={handleChange(i)} />
```

```
const handleChange = (i) => (e) => {
  setNewQuestion({
    ...newQuestion,
    answers: newQuestion.answers.map((answer, j) => j !== i ? answer : ({
      ...answer,
      answerText: e.target.value
    }))
  });
};
```

For the question text, change to

```
onChange={(e) => setNewQuestion(({ ...newQuestion, question: e.target.value }))}
```

But it'd make more sense to separate out the question text and the answers array into separate state variables:

```
const [questionText, setQuestionText] = useState('');
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([{
  answerText: 'here',
  // ...
```

which will make navigating around, referencing, and updating the state a bit less tedious.

Comment: now the question itself doesn't change, but the answers change, should I just duplicate the old function?

Comment: It's ugly since the question text and answers are inside a single state variable. Separate them out if you can.